How to update VS 2022 from notification
I usually update the visual studio 2022 (currently on Version 17.10.6) installed on my machine from the notifications page - a link appears there and and it lets me set it to update on close of VS, at which point the visual studio installer pops up and I can update the VS installed on my machine.
But I dont see those messages anymore.
I have tried check for updates from the menu, but it pops up a CLI help dialog that doesnt help me:

I have even tried running the visual studio installer from the windows menu - it opens, but doesnt show anything as installed

What am I missing?

The issue generally is due to the folder _Instances or subfolder in it under your download cache folder (The default path is %programdata%\Microsoft\visualstudio\packages) has been removed or corrupted.
Try deleting the Visual Studio Installer folder, and then rerunning the installation bootstrapper can solve certain update failures. Doing so reinstalls the Visual Studio Installer files and resets the installation metadata.

Close the Visual Studio Installer.
Delete the Visual Studio Installer folder. Typically, the folder
path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer.
Run the Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper. You might find the
bootstrapper in your Downloads folder with a file name
VisualStudioSetup.exe (Visual Studio 2022) or vs_*.exe
(Visual Studio 2019 and previous versions). Or, you can download the
bootstrapper from the download pages for Visual Studio 2022 or
Visual Studio 2019 and previous versions.Then, run the executable to reset your installation metadata.
Try to install or update Visual Studio again. If the Visual Studio
Installer continues to fail, report a problem to support.

refer to :  installation - Why can't the Visual Studio installer always find any local Visual Studio IDE? - Stack OverflowTroubleshoot installation and upgrade issues - Visual Studio | Microsoft Lea
